# How can I create this component in Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to create an app that will vertically list components with some basic github information.

I originally had this

[image: Current progress]

I want to replace the buttons with clickable frames (or at least frames with buttons) that look like this:

```
____________________________________
|_____JLabel_____|_____JLabel______|
|                                  |
|_________Fixed-length label_______|
|                                  |
|_______________Button_____________|
```

I'm pretty new to Swing development, so I don't know any design idioms. Please excuse the messy code. Here's what I've tried.

```
JPanel [] panels;

private void createStubs(PriorityQueue<Issue> issues) {

    int i = 0;
    while(!issues.isEmpty()) {
        Issue issue = issues.poll();

        // Create components
        JPanel panOuter = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel panTop = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        JPanel panTopRight = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel panTopLeft = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel panMiddle = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel panBottom = new JPanel();

        panTop.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));


        panTopLeft.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        panTopRight.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        panBottom.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        panMiddle.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        // Add components to content panel
        panOuter.add(panMiddle, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panOuter.add(panBottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panOuter.add(panTop, BorderLayout.NORTH);


        JLabel lblTopLeft = new JLabel(issue.getTitle(), JLabel.CENTER);
        JLabel lblTopRight = new JLabel(issue.getAuthor().getLogin(), JLabel.CENTER);


        JLabel lblCenter = new JLabel(issue.getBodyShort(), JLabel.CENTER);

        JButton btnBottom = new JButton("Check out this issue");

        panMiddle.add(lblCenter);
        panBottom.add(btnBottom);

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

        panTopLeft.add(lblTopLeft, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panTopRight.add(lblTopRight, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        panTop.add(panTopLeft, gbc);
        panTop.add(panTopRight, gbc);   


        panOuter.add(panMiddle, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panOuter.add(panBottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panOuter.add(panTop, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        addPanels(panOuter, i);

        ++i;
    }
}

private void addPanels(JPanel panel, int i) {
    panels[i] = panel;
    add(panels[i]);
}
```

So it now looks like this

[image: Little better]

How can I actually make the title and author be on the same line? It would also be nice to add line breaks between the issues and to make it scrollable.

Thanks,
erip

Comment: Add an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to achieve your desired layout. Here I use `GridBagLayout` for the inner panels. I added colors just to show the space the component takes.
The containing panel uses `GridLayout` and is added to a scroll pane.

[image]

```
public class Test extends JFrame {

    Test() {

        JPanel main = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i ++)
            main.add(new IssuePanel());

        getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(main));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private class IssuePanel extends JPanel {

        IssuePanel() {

            setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLUE));
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

            JLabel topLeft = new JLabel("Top Left");
            topLeft.setOpaque(true);
            topLeft.setBackground(Color.RED);
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 0;
            add(topLeft, c);

            JLabel topRight = new JLabel("Top Right");
            topRight.setOpaque(true);
            topRight.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            c.gridx = 1;
            c.gridy = 0;
            add(topRight, c);

            JLabel middle = new JLabel("Middle");
            middle.setOpaque(true);
            middle.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 1;
            add(middle, c);

            JButton button = new JButton("Button");
            button.setOpaque(true);
            button.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 2;
            add(button, c);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Test();
    }
}
```

Comment: Very helpful and much cleaner. Thank you!